# operations on lists while unpacking

Tags: python, list

I have a list of strings:

```
my_list = ['text_1','ibno0d',' text_2 ' ]
```

And I want to save the first and third value in new variables:

a,_,b = my_list

Since text_1 and text_2 have some spaces I use strip method to clean those values.

```
a = a.strip()
b = b.strip()
```

I want to do this a the moment of the assignment, what I thought to do is:

```
my_list = [' text_1','ibno0d',' text_2 ' ]
a,_,b  = [text.strip() for text in my_list]
```

is there a better option to acomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer using `map` for this..

```
a, _, b = map(str.strip, my_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate only over the indexes you are interested about. Doesn't matter too much here but in case list is longer it makes a difference:

```
a, b = (my_list[i].strip() for i in [0, 2])
```

Answer (score -1):

```
a = my_list[0].strip()
b = my_list[2].strip()
```